# Kendo Chart - Angular2 choose which axis my data will use

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-chart

I am trying to do a scatter chart, with two seperate datasets, with different Y-Axis.

The second series should use the second Y-Axis, how do I achieve this?

```
<kendo-chart [title]="" style="height:290px">
  <kendo-chart-series>
    <kendo-chart-series-item type="scatterLine"
                             [data]="chartRunData"
                             xField="date" yField="duration">
    </kendo-chart-series-item>

    <kendo-chart-series-item type="scatter"
                             [data]="chartAlarmData"
                             xField="date" yField="level"  >
    </kendo-chart-series-item>



  </kendo-chart-series>

  <kendo-chart-x-axis>
    <kendo-chart-x-axis-item [title]="{ text: 'Time' }" [max]="maxDate" [min]="minDate">
    </kendo-chart-x-axis-item>
  </kendo-chart-x-axis>
  <kendo-chart-y-axis> 
    <kendo-chart-y-axis-item [title]="{ text: 'Duration [seconds]' }">
    </kendo-chart-y-axis-item>
    <kendo-chart-y-axis-item [title]="{ text: 'Alarm Level' }" [max]="5" min="0">
    </kendo-chart-y-axis-item>
  </kendo-chart-y-axis>
</kendo-chart>
```

Answer (score 0):

Very simple answer - specify a yAxis name.

```
<kendo-chart [title]="" style="height:290px">
  <kendo-chart-series>
    <kendo-chart-series-item type="scatterLine"
                             [data]="chartRunData"
                             xField="date" yField="duration">
    </kendo-chart-series-item>

    <kendo-chart-series-item type="scatter"
                             [data]="chartAlarmData"
                               yField="level" yAxis="'alarmLevel'" >
    </kendo-chart-series-item>



  </kendo-chart-series>

  <kendo-chart-x-axis>
    <kendo-chart-x-axis-item [title]="{ text: 'Time' }" [max]="maxDate" [min]="minDate">
    </kendo-chart-x-axis-item>
  </kendo-chart-x-axis>
  <kendo-chart-y-axis> 
    <kendo-chart-y-axis-item [title]="{ text: 'Duration [seconds]' }">
    </kendo-chart-y-axis-item>
    <kendo-chart-y-axis-item [title]="{ text: 'Alarm Level' }" [max]="5" min="0" name="'alarmLevel'">
    </kendo-chart-y-axis-item>
  </kendo-chart-y-axis>
</kendo-chart>
```